# Score on synonyms suggestion page

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, tag-score

Recently I got the privilege to suggest tag synonyms. I've tried it whenever I found any, sometimes I have to see as per requirements for suggestion:

> [image: required score message]

My suggestion is, to show the user their current score for a particular tag on this page i.e,

> Your score for [legal](/questions/tagged/legal) is 3, You need at-least a score of 5 in this tag to suggest a synonym

If the user is not allowed to suggest it should be shown in red.

Comment: I don't see the use in making an error message dynamic in order to show a number *that* low. It would only be one of 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. I think saying "it's currently less than 5" is *plenty* efficient, and it doesn't require a dynamic error message.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe suppressing / hiding the 'suggest a synonym' option for tags you're not qualified to suggest a synonym for would be another option -- skip the error message altogether that way, and doesn't waste your time/effort.